# Let $G$ be the group of non-zero complex numbers under multiplication and let $H=\{z \in\mathbb C :z^n=1\}$. Find the cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

What I think is that the cosets are going to be $zH$ where $z^q=1$, where $q$ is an irrational number.

Proving the cosets are distinct:
Let $z^{q_1}H =z^{q_2}H$ then $z^{q_1 -q_2} \in H$ which would probably mean that $q_1-q_2=n$. I need some help.

Comment: The subgroup $H$ is cyclic of order $n$ generated by $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$.

So $zH=\lbrace ze^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}~\mid~ k=0,\dots, n-1\rbrace$.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} = S \times \mathbb{R}_+$ where $S =\{z: |z|=1\}$ and $\mathbb{R}_+$ is the multiplicative group of positive real numbers. This can be seen by the polar/trigonometric form of the complex number $z \mapsto (e^{i\arg{z}},|z|)$

Now, we can prove that $S/H \cong \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are the additive groups.

Let $\phi \colon \mathbb{R} \to S/H$ be the group homomorphism described by $\theta \mapsto [e^{2\pi i\theta}]$. If $\theta \in \ker \phi$ then $e^{2n\pi i \theta}=1$, which means that $ \theta = \frac{k}{n} $ for some $k$ and $n$. That is, $\mathbb{Q} \supset \ker\phi$. Since $\mathbb{Q} \subset \ker \phi$ we have the result by Isomorphism Theorems.

So $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}/H \cong \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 0):

The notation leads me to believe that what is meant is "the group $\mathbb C \backslash \{ 0 \}$ of all non-zero complex numbers under multiplication" and that $n$ is meant to be either "non-negative integer" or "positive integer." If $n=0$ then $H=\mathbb C \backslash \{ 0 \}$ and there is only one coset, $\mathbb C \backslash \{ 0 \}.$ If $n=1,$ then $H= \{1\}$ and the cosets are  all the $\{z\}$ for $z \in \mathbb C \backslash \{ 0 \}$. If $n>1$ then the cosets are all the $$\{z \text {cis}\frac{2\pi 1}{n},...,z \text {cis}\frac{2\pi n}{n}\}$$ for $z \in \mathbb C \backslash \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: The question that was given to me was that$ n$ can be any natural number. @P. Lawrence

Comment: But you have defined $H$ as though $n$ is a fixed number.